# return variable in if statement - multiple attempts possible?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, return

i am unsure weather i am terming this correctly, but i think the following code will be pretty self explaintory:

```
function a($p){
    if($p===true){
        return 'yep';
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

if($test=a(true)){
    echo $test; // this will echo out 'yep'
}
```

the above code works as expected. what i am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
function a($p){
    if($p===true){
        return 'yep';
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

if($test=a(false)||$test=a(true)){
    var_dump($test); // this will show $test being bool(true) NOT yep
}
```

is this possible without doing an intermediate function?

i have also tried:

```
if($test=(a(false)||a(true)){ ... }
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$test = a(false) || $test = a(true)
```

will be evaluated as

```
$test = ( a(false) || $test=a(true) )
```

Logical operators always return a boolean value, so the result of the `||` expression will be assigned to `$test`.

If you want that the expressions above assigns the string to `$test`, then you have use `or` which has a [lower precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) then the assignment operator ( I would prefer this way in this context):

```
$test = a(false) or $test = a(true)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/bIp3Q3Mz)

Or you set the parenthesis correctly:

```
($test = a(false)) || ($test = a(true))
```

Comment: frustrating how i cant vote this answer as correct for another 10 minutes. solved! thanks!!!